# Combining Spring Security Tags and Struts2 Tags

Tags: struts2, spring-security, taglib

I'm currently using Spring Security to manage login and sessions on my Struts2 application.
To retrieve the logged user in a JSP page I'm using the sec tag lib by importing the following  to my jsp.

`<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>`

So to print my logged user i use `<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />`.

I'm iterating through a `java.util.List` received through the action called, so a iterate it through something like this:

```
<s:iterator value="#request.myList" var="userEmail">
    My value: <s:property value="#userEmail"/>
</s:iterator>
```

I'm looking for a way to test the list item to check if is the same as the logged user, but I can't manage to retrieve `sec` inside a `<s:if>` tag.

Does anyone know how to combine both? and do something like

`<s:if test="%{<sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> == #userEmail}">`

Comment: Can you use something like `<s:set var="foo"><sec:authentication ...></s:set>` and use `#foo` inside the test? I'm not 100% convinced this logic should be in the view layer, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I agree that the idea of keeping such test on the view layer seems odd, but it's related to deciding about showing certain styles and divs.

Comment: I meant the access to the principal username. At the least I'd wrap this up in a custom tag. Although I guess if it's just for use while iterating over a list like this it's probably not worth it.

Comment: BTW, tried your suggestion, and it did'nt work, The accepted answer worked though.

Comment: Dave solution should work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using information from session:

```
<s:if test="#session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.username == #userEmail">
```