# Access the current logged in user username with spring security in the view

Tags: grails, spring-security, textfield, gsp

How can I access the current logged in user username with springSecurity in the gsp view, or more specifically, use this value in a textfield?

This solution below doesn't work:

> value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:'username')}"

Comment: what is the error? it would help to include a stacktrace, as "doesn't work" is pretty vague.

Comment: i don't have error but it doesn't show anything in the textfield

Comment: I fear you won't be able to use the `sec` taglib because it lways writes to the DOM. You can use `springSecurityService.authentication.name` in `controller` action and set the value in `model` which can be used in the view, unless there is nay direct process I am not cognizant of.

Comment: Assuming your user is logged in successfully, what you have here should work, also you can try <input type="text" value="${sec.username()}">. I tested both and they both worked on text box. If it didnt work follow dmahapatro approach and make sure  authentication.name is not empty.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16444220/1700321.

Comment: i try this solution  <input type="text" value="${sec.username()}"> and i have this error  doFilter in \grails-app\views\da\create.gsp

Comment: sorry this is the error message : Unclosed GSP expression

Answer (score 6):

The following lines both work correctly in my test.

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="${sec.username()}" />
<input name="username" type="text" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}" />
```

Error you've got might be from other place. Could you test by only use that input tag in GSP?

Comment: i try it even in another GSP and i have the same problem not error but i have nothing in the textfield it is empty

Comment: Both solutions worked for me too (I exactly wrote: `<p> "${sec.username()}" </p>`). Maybe there is not any user logged in @zgaw87?

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Taglib Option** to get various information about the logged in the user into the view.

**ExamplNameTagLib.groovy**

```
class ExamplNameTagLib {

   static namespace = 'foo'

   def springSecurityService


   def currentUserProps = { attrs ->
      def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
      if (user) {
         if (attrs.username) {
             out << user.username 
         } else if (attrs.firstName) {
             out << user.firstName
         } else if (attrs.lastName) {
             out << user.lastName
         } else if (attrs.email) {
             out << user.email
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**exampleViewPage.gsp**

```
//Return username from taglib of the logged in user
<g:field type="text" 
         name="username" 
         value="${foo.currentUserProps(username: true)}" />

//Return email from taglib of the logged in user
<g:field type="email" 
         name="email" 
         value="${foo.currentUserProps(email: true)}"/>
```